# Label tag is not moving the form structure in line

Tags: php, html

The label tag has the right syntax however the form structure is not aligned well the way I want it.I also put id as well

```
 echo "<form action='getregister.php' method='post'>";
echo "<fieldset >";
echo "<legend>Register</legend>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>";
echo "<label for='First_name'>First Name: </label>";
echo "<input type='text' name='U_fname' id='First_name' value=''><br>";
echo "<label for='Last_name'>Last Name: </label>";
echo "<input type='text' name='U_sname' id='Last_name' value=''><br>";
echo "<label for='Address' >Address: </label>";
echo "<input type='text' name='U_address' id='Address' value=''><br>";
echo "<label for='Postcode' >Postcode: </label>";
echo "<input type='text' name='U_postcode' id='Postcode' value=''><br>";
echo "<label for='Telno' >Tel No: </label>";
echo "<input type='text' name='U_telNo' id='Telno' value=''><br>";
echo "<label for='Email' >Email Address: </label>";
echo "<input type='email' name='U_email' id='Email' value=''><br>";
echo "<label for='password' >Password:</label>";
echo "<input type='password' name='U_password' id='password' value=''><br>";
echo "<label for='passwords' >Confirm Password:</label>";
echo "<input type='password' name='U_confirmPassword' id='passwords' value=''><br>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Register' />";
echo "<button type='reset' value='Reset'>Clear form</button>";
echo "</fieldset>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: `<label>` doesn't have any special layout. You need to use a table or CSS to align things.

Comment: What exactly is the way you want it? I also don't see how PHP is relevant here. This seems like a purely HTML/CSS issue.

Comment: and why there are `for` attributes with no matching `id`s for the inputs?

Comment: @j08691 I want all the form fields to the left and all aligned

Comment: try \n at end of each echo

Comment: @Omi what do you mean

Comment: is it fine if it display label on first line then on second line input and so on

Comment: @Omi All I want is the textbox aligned and first name etc

Comment: if you want side by side with aligned then try to use table n set border none

Comment: @Omi would that go under css

Comment: you can do that with inline css also

Comment: @Omi can I do css inline  with a php file

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
echo "<form action='getregister.php' method='post'>";
echo "<fieldset >";
echo "<legend>Register</legend>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>";
echo "<table>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><label for='First_name' >First Name: </label></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='U_fname' value=''></td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><label for='Last_name'>Last Name: </label></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='U_sname' id='Last_name' value=''>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<table>";
echo "</fieldset>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Register' />";
echo "<td><button type='reset' value='Reset'>Clear form</button></td>";
echo "</tr>";     i did this for the register button and clear form is this right

Comment: yes you are right,it ll align two button side by side

Comment: You might want to get in the habit of accepting answers if they solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers